# Friend Request System - Express, MongoDB, EJS

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, social-networking

I want to create a social network thus allowing users to send and interact with frind requests. As of now I have created the register, log-in and "search for other users function".

When I find and select another user, I display their user-info and have created a "Add friend" button.

Can anyone help me in a direction of the creation of the "Add friend" option? I have looked around for some time now, and not been able to find the correct solution. Below I have attached my UserSchema and route for finding users:

```
//User Schema
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
},{ collection: 'Users' });




//Get single user based on ID
router.get('/user/get:id', ensureAuthenticated, function (req, res) {
    MongoClient.connect(DBUri,{useUnifiedTopology: true }, function (err, db) {
        let dbo = db.db(DBName);
        const query = {_id: objectId(req.params.id)}
        dbo.collection("Users").find(query).toArray(function(err, resultTasks) {
            if (err) throw err;
            res.render('../View/findFriend', {
                resultTasks: resultTasks
            });
            db.close();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you describe what you expect of _"the correct solution"_? What is your specific problem or question? I you're looking for ideas you can find projects like: https://github.com/opensource-socialnetwork/opensource-socialnetwork/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add something like this in your user schema:

`friends: [{ type : ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],`

OR

`friends: userSchema`

Take the one which suits you.

What that will do is add an array to the user, Then you can store IDs of friends.(Who are other users, hence the `ref: 'User'`)

Then, When you have to fetch users you can do:

`User.find(<ID or whatever you have to find Users>).populate('friends')`

Also, To push a new friend simply use: `user.friends.push(newFriend._id)`